# Perl Regex for ignore word and same accented word

Tags: regex

I need regex for perl or similar to ignore word and same accented word, like

esta, está, ésta, estä

My need is something lik `[^\w\s]` is anything that's not a digit, letter, whitespace, or underscore, but for ignore that in spanish accented word

`confirme`, `confirmé`

Comment: *I need regex for perl or similar* sounds as *take Bus 5 or similar* to a stranger. Could you precise? Please share the code you have come up so far.

Comment: If you use Perl, all you need to do is add `use utf8;` for your [regex to start matching Unicode symbols](https://ideone.com/qvKjY7).

Comment: So are you trying to turn all of these words: está, ésta, estä into just esta? I guess, why are you trying to ignore them? and what are you trying to match (sample input and outputs would be helpful)?

Answer (score 0):

I need only a regex for ignore está and esta, only same words but with different accent, please view sample out: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/75366808/diff_Nov-10-2015%2021-47.htm
I need ignore
"que está cometiendo"
and
"que esta cometiendo"

Tnks